# How to stop a method from returning to the calling method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and can not find the answer to my problem, hope someone can help.  I have 2 method both are actionresults and both return views. The problem I am having is that the first method calls the second method and that creates a viewmodel and assigns the located data to the view model and then returns the view.  But the problem I am having is the second method returns to the first method and the view of the first method is displayed instead of the view of the second method.  My question is how do I stop the second method from returning to the first method and have the view from the second method execute. I hope I made this clear.  Thanks here is my code.

first method

```
        [Route("confirmuser")]
    public ActionResult ConfirmUser()
    {
        var cacId = Request.ClientCertificate["SubjectCN"];
        var validUser = LocateUser(cacId);
        switch (validUser)
        {
            case "ActiveUser":
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "ActiveUser");
            case "MultipleUserTypes":
                MultipleUserType();
                break;
            case "Inactive":
                return View(AccountMessage(validUser));
            case "Locked":
                return View(AccountMessage(validUser));
            case "Disabled":
                return View(AccountMessage(validUser));
            case "New":
                break;
            case "UserNotFound":
                return View(AccountMessage(validUser));
        } //end switch
        return View();
    }
```

second method

```
    [Route("multipleusertype")]
    public ActionResult MultipleUserType()
    {
        var user = (UserInfo)Session["user"];

        var usertype = GetAllUserTypes(user.Id);
        var multipleUserType = new ActiveUserViewModel();

        multipleUserType.UserTypes = usertype;

        return View(multipleUserType);
    }
```

Comment: If you need some code from another method then take that code only and create a new method that returns something more generic that you can use. As an example in another method you could put the switch statement and return just the AccountMessage and use that anywhere.

Comment: `I hope I made this clear` not really. Most likely you confuse functions in general and actions. A method always returns to its caller. `return View(multipleUserType)` doesn't send anything to the renderer either. It's the middleware that called the action in the first place that's going to get that `ActionResult` and render it into HTML. In this case it looks like all you need is `return MultipleUserType();` although a **far better solution** would be to extract the code that generates `multipleUserType` into a separate method and call that.

Comment: An action specifies a route, performs vaildations, returns ActionResult instances etc. If you try to use one action inside another, you end up applying the validations of one action to the other, which is almost always *not* what you wanted. Modifying the first action is a lot harder too, as it risks breaking its caller. Instead of reusing code, you ended up cementing the two actions together

Comment: Here's a simple rule of thumb: If you find yourself calling one action method from another action method, then your code structure is wrong. An action method should only be called in response to an action taken by the user in the browser - think of action methods as your application's interface to the outside world. Therefore, they are not something to be used internally, so you shouldn't be calling one directly from your C# code.

Comment: Most likely you need to have a 3rd (normal, non-action) method which returns the data you're interested in, which can be shared by both action methods. Either that, or your first action method should be _redirecting_ the browser to the second one

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `return` keyword :

```
case "MultipleUserTypes":
            return  MultipleUserType();
```

As someone commented, this is a quick fix and public action methods are not intended to be called like that. You really should refactor to a private method encapsulating the shared logic.

Comment: That's a quick fix, but won't solve the real problem - using one action from inside another

Comment: You are totally right, that's not recommandable at all. But it does answer the question I think.